# How to display text when mouse hovers over a button using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have been given a .cshtml file in which 4 buttons are created (code attached below). All 4 buttons have the same class and id and also I can't edit the .cshtml file. Now, I have to display particular text for each button when the mouse hovers over them with the help of the .js file.

**.cshtml file**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 PT10">
                <div class="text-center">
                    @{
                    
                        foreach (var opt in ViewBag.BusinessTypes)
                        {
                            <button id="selectOption" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="validateAddressAndUpdateOption('@opt.Key')" onmouseover="textOnMouseOver">
                                @opt.Value
                            </button>
                        }

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: where is js code ? Also ,where is that text which you need to display ?

Comment: Hi Swati, I have to create the js file in order to display the text.

Comment: which text ? please add that information as well in your asked question . Also did you check [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `title` to add particular text for buttons when mouse hovers over them.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class BusinessType {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestJs() {
            ViewBag.BusinessTypes = new List<BusinessType> { new BusinessType { Key = "1", Value = "1" }, new BusinessType { Key = "2", Value = "2" }, new BusinessType { Key = "3", Value = "3" } };
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 PT10">
        <div class="text-center">
            @{

                foreach (var opt in ViewBag.BusinessTypes)
                {
                    <button id="selectOption" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="validateAddressAndUpdateOption('@opt.Key')"  title="My key is @(opt.Key)">
                        @opt.Value
                    </button>
                }

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**
you can use js to foreach the buttons and add title to them:

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 PT10">
        <div class="text-center">
            @{

                foreach (var opt in ViewBag.BusinessTypes)
                {
                    <button id="selectOption" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="validateAddressAndUpdateOption('@opt.Key')" >
                        @opt.Value
                    </button>
                }

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
$(function () {
            var count = 1;
            $(".text-center button").each(function () {
                switch (count) {
                    case 1:
                        $(this).attr("title", "Hello, User");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $(this).attr("title", "What would you like to have");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $(this).attr("title", "Bye, User!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                count++;
            })
        })

</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got the logic but I want the text of button 1 to be "Hello, User", button 2 to be "What would you like to have" and that of button 3 to be "Bye, User!".

Comment: You can use js to add title rather than adding title in html code directly.You can refer to the updated answer.

Comment: I used your updated code but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Did your js work?Have you put it into <script></script>？

Comment: Hello,have you use `<script></script>` as my updated answer shown,And I have updated my code format.The previous format is wrong,and `div` code is not shown in the updated answer.